# Print text when a rectangle is pressed libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

i have created a rectangle

```
public Rectangle rectangle_hitbox;
```

It has the coordinates and dimensions of the enemies. In the render method, I want that when this rectangle is pressed, the string "Done" is printed. I tried with:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
   System.out.println("Done");
} else {
   System.out.println("Missed");
}
```

But it works anywhere on the map and not only in rectangles

Answer (score 0):

The `Gdx.input.isTouched()` method doesn't know about the position of your rectagle. It just check whether the screen is touched or not.

Try using `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()` to get the coordinates of the click or touch event when the screen is touched and check these coordinates against the coordinates of your rectangle.

Also don't forget to **unproject** the coordinates if you are using a `camera`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997489/8178842) for more information.

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0f);
    // TODO maybe unproject the position using camera.unproject(touchPosition);
    if (isTouchInsideRectangle(touchPosition)) {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Missed");
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i use this i don't need rectangle, but it works wiith images